# Adding event listener to all embedded YouTube video via a WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, dom-events, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to implement a function which is called whenever any HTML5 (YouTube) video is played on any web site. I tried either with the API:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("playing", function(){
    alert("Video playing")
});
```

and with jQuery:

```
$('video').on('playing', function(){
    alert("Video Playing");
});
```

But, both are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. For those, who are interested:

The content-Script needs to be initialized in the manifest like that:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>],
     "js": ["name_of_javascript.js"]
     "run_at" "document_idle"  // "document_end" also works
     "all_frames":true
    }
 ],
   ...
```

it´s important to add the tag "all_frames":true, so that the content-script is injected to all subframes.

Content_Script-Code:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
if(videos.length>0) {
   for (var i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
        videos[i].addEventListener("playing", function(e){
          ................
          }
      }
 };
```

This worked for me.

If you want to add the Listener just for Youtube-Videos, just replace the document.getElementsbyTagName with document.querySelectAll('video[src*="youtube"]').

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('wraperElementId', {
        height: '220',
        width: '220',
        videoId: 'video id from the url',
        playerVars: {showinfo:0, autoplay:0},
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

}
```

UPDATE:
You need to get the site videos in order to manipulate them.
Here is an example using jQuery:

```
var iframes=$('iframe').filter(function(index){// get all youtube iframes
    return ( (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-  nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(this.src))
             && (this.offsetHeight >= 315) && (this.offsetWidth >= 400) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the main problem is, that i´m not implementing the website by myself. I just want to start a function via WebExtensions contentscript, if any Video is started on any WebPage.

Comment: you neet to get the videos of the website first. i updated the answer to show you how

Comment: Downvoting, since YT API will not work in content scripts in this form (because of [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` and `onPlayerStateChange` are not accessible to the loaded API script) and the question is _specifically_ about (Web)Extensions.